Core dump is not generated
I am using the template from https://github.com/userver-framework/service_template After build i run service_template_unittest and got segfault. I want to get core dump (Ubuntu 22.04) but it is not generated
I am using ulimit -c unlimited but it doesn't work. I created simple program that cause segfault and core dump was generated for it. In apport.log: For my program

ERROR: apport (pid 3791) Tue Jun 18 17:46:44 2024: writing core dump
to
core._home_avru_projects_Training_segfault_out.1000.866516bf-26cc-412a-a973-71d92789ec77.3790.139499
(limit: -1)

For service_template_unittest:

called for pid 13297, signal 11, core limit 0, dump mode 1

For some reason core limit appears to be 0 and i don't know why
